# Wepback import html template not loading

Tags: angularjs, webpack, systemjs, es6-module-loader, webpack-3

I have a monolith project made with AngularJS using Webpack but I'm getting an error saying: `Unexpected token < main.html.` This error occurs when I have this line of code in one of my controllers:

```
 import templateUrl from './main.html';
```

From my understanding, it looks to me that Webpack does not bundle correctly my HTML template. the `<` symbol is coming from the main.html template, it is found with success but not parsed. I then thought about using `html-loader` and use it that way:

```
 import templateUrl from 'html-loader!./main.html';
```

To my great surprise, this does not solve the issue.

I am using Webpack version `"webpack": "^3.4.1",` and this is my config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = 
require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';

const styles = [
 'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
 'postcss-loader',
 'sass-loader'
];

module.exports = {
 entry: {
    'root-application': 'src/root-application/root-application.js',
},
output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: !isProd
                ? [
                    'style-loader',
                    ...styles
                ]
                : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: styles
                }),
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            use: ['url-loader?limit=100000']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                'ngtemplate-loader',
                'html-loader'
            ],
            exclude: /(index)/
        },
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
    ],
},
node: {
    fs: 'empty'
},
resolve: {
    modules: [
        __dirname,
        'node_modules',
    ],
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'common-dependencies',
    }),
    new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    )
],
devtool: 'source-map',
externals: [],
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
 }
};
```

I've checked other SO topic about `Unexpected token <`, I am sure that there is no 404 - Not found error in my network tab.

Comment: we have code like this:

import controller from './ctrl.ctrl';

component = {
 bindings: {
 },
 controller: controller,
 template: require('./template.html')
};
[So require for html instead of import]

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Why this should matter? There is plenty of example importing HTML template with import keyword in AngularJS app. But I give it a try since I ran out of ideas.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I tried and for some reason it will now append `.js` to all my HTML file which result to an error - 404 not found. I'm not sure this is a right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is fundamentally taking the problem from a different tack, by not using the `templateUrl` property to load your directive's templates, but I've used this angularjs & webpack configuration to great effect; it also saves HTTP requests, by inlining the templates.

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Load raw HTML files for inlining our templates
      { test: /\.(html)$/, loader: "raw-loader" },
      // ... other rules, config, etc.
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, in a directive file:

```
import templateString from './wherever.template.html'

function directiveFunc() {
  return {
    // template, rather than templateUrl   
    template: templateString,
    // ...
  }
}

export default directiveFunc
```

Install the `raw-loader` loader with:

```
$ npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use [angular2-template-loader](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader) instead of the generic one.

Comment: Think that I'm not using Angular but AngularJS.

Comment: Your dependencies clearly say you are, but anyway, there is a similar package for ng1

Comment: You're right, this is because I'm prototyping single-spa and will need it for later.